# Tikiwiki How do I set the "User_Tracker_Business" profile?

Tags: content-management-system, tiki-wiki

**I'm using**
Tikiwiki 17.x.

When I installed Tikiwiki I got to the page (see the screenshot).
When the "User_Tracker_Business" profile began to appear, a message appears:

"An error occurred during the profile validation.
Message: Unknown objects are referenced: http: //profiles.tiki.org \ / User_Tracker "

**QUESTION**
Are there any other ways to set the "User_Tracker_Business" profile?
What should I do to install the "User_Tracker_Business" profile?
For which versions of Tikiwiki can I install the "User_Tracker_Business" profile?
Where can I see the "User_Tracker_Business" profile?

**scr**
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it Tiki 17.x latest checkout from SVN or released 17.0? What OS is your Tiki installed one? I cannot reproduce the error on my Tiki 17.x from SVN.

Regarding your questions:

> Q: Are there any other ways to set the "User_Tracker_Business"
>   profile?
>
> A:  Yes, from command line php console.php profile:apply
>   User_Tracker_Business (see https://doc.tiki.org/Console for doc)
>
> Q:  What should I do to install the "User_Tracker_Business" profile?
>
> A: It should work without error.
>
> Q: For which versions of Tikiwiki can I
>   install the "User_Tracker_Business" profile?
>
> A:  12.x to 17.x as the profile suggests
>
> Q: Where can I see the "User_Tracker_Business"
>   profile?
>
> A:  See https://profiles.tiki.org/User_Tracker_Business

Please note that this profile installs just the Tracker. If you want a user profile page for each user to display the information from the tracker apply User_Profile_Business instead.

luci